# Best software for interactive info graphics

Tags: vector-graphics, animation, touchscreen

I have a wide touch screen wall, I'm building a interactive info graphic. Which software is recommended for building HD interactive infographic with animations. The animated elements I'm looking for is like HUD futuristic elements that will be interactive svg.